# State Monads in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

I am writing a function in Haskell that takes in a Java class file, and writes another class file that is identical but contains some modifications. For this, I feel that I definitely need a state monad to at least hold the [Word8] that holds all of the bytes of the class file. However, after all of my research on State Monads in Haskell, I am still having trouble figuring out how to do this. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I would like to be able to have a [Word8] (or you know, any data type) that is in scope for all of the functions and that I can modify from functions. I understand this involves using something like 
state<-get
...
put newstate

but I really don't know where to start with defining the monad and whatnot.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230562/confusion-over-the-state-monad-code-on-learn-you-a-haskell

Comment: What sort of transformations are you going to be doing to the bytes?  Are you inserting and deleting chunks?  Do you need random access?  Before you worry about which monad you need, first figure out what data structure you need.  That's far more important.

Comment: Also, I'm guessing that the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253474/inject-a-function-into-a-java-class-file-using-haskell) will be of use to you.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure you *do* want a `State` monad. Depending on what kind of modifications you want to make, you *are* allowed to just pass the data you want to modify to every function that wants to modify it. `State` is usually for situations where you are producing a value *in addition* to modifying state, i.e. when you are writing a lot of functions that look like `s -> (s,a)`.

Try just a normal-function approach first. `State` isn't magic, it just makes certain types of code easier to write quickly, concisely, and correctly. Everything you can do with it you can also do without it, it's just a bit more tedious.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up just using a lot of normal-functions that kind of emulated state changes. In case anyone was curious, the project involved reading in the class file, separating it into its parts, and adding code to the methods to print out the name of the method when entering it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

What you probably want, instead of the State Monad, is the ST monad and mutable vectors.

Use the IO monad to read the bytes in from the class file.

```
bytes <- readFile myClassFile
```

use `runST` to run your `ST` monad calculation on the given bytes:

```
let result = runST $ transform bytes
```

The ST monad gives you access to [mutable vectors](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.9.1/doc/html/Data-Vector.html#t%3aMVector), which are a lot like C or Java arrays.  They're indexed by integers, and have O(1) lookup and modify.

```
transform :: [Char] -> ST s [Char]
transform bytes = do
   mvec <- thaw $ fromList bytes
   -- you can read a value at an index
   val <- read mvec 0
   -- and set a value at an index
   write mvec 0 (val `xor` 0xff)
   -- ...
   -- turn it back into a list of bytes
   vec <- freeze mvec
   return $ toList vec
```

So just pass around the `mvec` to all your functions (which must return a ST action), and you'll be able to do whatever you want to the bytes.

If you don't want to bother with passing it as an argument, consider using the `ReaderT` monad transform to make the `mvec` implicitily available to all your code.

```
transform bytes = do
   -- ...
   runReaderT other mvec
   --- ... 

other :: ReaderT (MVector s Char) (ST s) String 
other = do
   -- ...
   -- grab the mvec when you need it
   mvec <- ask
   val <- lift $ read mvec 77
   lift $ write mvec 77 (val * 363 - 28)
   -- ...
   return "Hi!"
```

Of course, this is all assuming you need random access to the bytes.  If you don't... then you probably don't need an `MVector`.

For example, if all you need to do is replace every instance of `0xDEADBEEF` with `0xCAFEBABE`, you could just use lists, no ST monad required:

```
 let newBytes = intsToBytes . map (\i -> if i == 0xDEADBEEF then 0xCAFEBABE else i) $ bytesToInts bytes
```

Comment: Mutable vectors get you O(1) read and write, but insertion & deletion are O(n), so I'm not sure that's the best choice unless you're sure that you are not changing the number of bytes in the classfile.

Comment: @DanBurton: You know, I didn't even think that Pha3drus might be doing that.  Good call!